# Blitting in tkinter frame

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am building a GUI that needs to plot multiple graphs from a csv as if they were live. I orignally built this using FuncAnimation, but once moved to a Raspberry Pi, this became too choppy. I decided to try blitting and updating the array I'm plotting, which worked great. However, I cannot transfer this into a my tkinter frame.

When I use fig.canvas, it seems to create a whole new window. But when I use `FigureCanvasTkAgg`, the `blitting` functions won't work. Is there a way to make `FigureCanvasTkAgg` work with `blitting`, or is there a way to assign fig.canvas to a master?

I did built a `BlitManager` class, but due to the trouble I've been having, I've simplified the code to see if I can get it to work. Here's the bulk of it.

```
class SeaofBTCapp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "Sea of BTC Client")

        container = tk.Frame(self, bg="whitesmoke")

        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (
            StartPage,
            PageOne,
        ):

            frame = F(container, self)

            self.frames[F] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):

        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()


def qf(quickPrint):
    print(quickPrint)


class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, bg="aliceblue")
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Home Page", font=LARGE_FONT, bg="aliceblue")
        label.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

        button = tk.Button(
            self,
            text="ECG",
            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageOne),
            font=MED_FONT,
            bg="lightseagreen",
            activebackground="seagreen",
        )
        button.pack(padx=10, pady=10)


class PageOne(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="HR", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

        label2 = tk.Label(self, text="HR = {}".format(round(HR)), font=LARGE_FONT)
        label2.pack()

        button1 = tk.Button(
            self,
            text="Back to Home",
            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage),
            font=MED_FONT,
        )
        button1.pack()
        
        y=ecg_h[0:300]

        fig, ax=plt.subplots()
        (line1, )= ax.plot(y, linewidth="0.75", animated=True)
        plt.show(block=False)
        plt.pause(0.1)
        #self.canvas=FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig,self)
        canvas=fig.canvas
        canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        bg = canvas.copy_from_bbox(fig.bbox)
        ax.draw_artist(line1)
        canvas.blit(fig.bbox)
        canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
        
        for i in range(301,len(ecg_h)-2):
            canvas.restore_region(bg)
            for j in range (300):
                y[300-(300-j)]=ecg_h[i+j]
            line1.set_ydata(y)
            ax.draw_artist(line1)
            canvas.blit(fig.bbox)
            canvas.flush_events()       
        

        #toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas2, self)
        #toolbar.update()
```

Comment: We cannot help if you are using older version 2.7. Everyone are using Python 3.7 or later. Why not you?

Comment: I am using python 3, that tag was a mistake

Comment: I have corrected the 2.7 tag